# How to read typical function documentation in Python?

Tags: python

Why does

```
class multiprocessing.Pool([processes[,initializer[,initargs[,maxtasksperchild]]]])
```

have all these `]]]]` included?

I don't understand how to read this structure?

Comment: Note that I understand that this seems like a stupid silly question (and I agree), but I can't find any official documentation on this kind of presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, in documentation, [`something`] is read like '`something` is optional'. In this particular case, it also implies dependency and should be read like this:

- `processes` is optional, but if you use it you can also use:
- `initializer`, which is optional, but if you use it you can also use:
- `initargs`, which is optional, but... and so on

Comment: So it can be ran with 0-4 arguments? simply separated with commas?

Comment: To make it short: Yes.

Answer (score 4):

"a phrase enclosed in square brackets ([ ]) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional)"

See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/introduction.html#notation

`[processes[,initializer[,initargs[,maxtasksperchild]]]]` means for instance that `initializer` is optional but if you use `initializer` you must also use `processes` and so on. This is what the embedded brackets mean.

If you do not name the parameters you can use in any of the following examples (but no other combination!):

```
Pool() 
Pool(processes) 
Pool(processes, initializer) 
Pool(processes, initializer, initargs) 
Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
```

Otherwise if you do name the parameteres you can use any of them optionally. The constructor has following default values:

```
Pool(processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(), maxtasksperchild=None)
```

See the source code of the constructor (https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/9d88b4875d6e/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py)

For more on keyword arguments you can read the following:
http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: I've seen multiple questions on stack overflow asking how to read Python documentation, and everyone else answers only the particular example presented. This is the first answer I've found that actually links to the answer for "how to read Python documentation".

Answer (score 2):

The use of `[]` indicates that the enclosed parameter is optional and can be omitted.